# Convert Array form (as String) to Column in Pyspark

Tags: arrays, pyspark, pivot

I have a df with this form:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|ID|ESTRUC_COMP                         |
+---------------------------------------+
|4A|{'AP': '201', 'BQ': '2'}            |
|8B| {'AP': '501', 'BQ': '1', 'IN': '5'}|
+---------------------------------------+
```

And I need something like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|ID|ESTRUC_COMP                        |AP |BQ|IN|
+------------------------------------------------+
|4A|{'AP': '201', 'BQ': '2'}           |201|2 |  |
|8B|{'AP': '501', 'BQ': '1', 'IN': '5'}|501|1 |5 |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

But, ESTRUC_COMP is a String.

```
root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ESTRUC_COMP: string (nullable = true)
```

How can I perform this transformation? Thank you in advance.

Boris

Comment: Maybe it is possible to transform the column to struct type and then apply the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874037/convert-pyspark-dataframe-column-from-array-to-new-columns?rq=1

Comment: What version of spark?

Comment: Hi @pault, 1.6.1

Comment: Dont' get it... I dont have a dict in column, I have a String column. I need to transforme it to dict or try to do the work using String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Spark 1.6, you can't use [`pyspark.sql.functions.from_json()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) - you're going to have to use a `udf`.

This question is very similar to [PySpark “explode” dict in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683894/pyspark-explode-dict-in-column), but I accept it's not a dupe for 2 reasons:

1. Your string column is not valid JSON (because of single quotes)
2. You want the keys to become columns

Nevertheless, the first step is to basically follow the same steps in the linked post with a minor tweak to the `parse()` function which replaces single quotes with double quotes:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, explode, first
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import json

def parse(s):
    try:
        return json.loads(s.replace("'", '"'))
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        pass

parse_udf = udf(parse, MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
```

Now you can parse the string and call [`pyspark.sql.functions.explode()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode):

```python
df.select("ID",  explode(parse_udf("ESTRUC_COMP"))).show()
#+---+---+-----+
#| ID|key|value|
#+---+---+-----+
#| 4A| BQ|    2|
#| 4A| AP|  201|
#| 8B| IN|    5|
#| 8B| BQ|    1|
#| 8B| AP|  501|
#+---+---+-----+
```

Finally, [`pivot()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot) to get the keys as the columns. You can use `first()` as the aggregate function because we know that the key-value relationship is one-to-one for each `ID`.

```python
df.select("*", explode(parse_udf("ESTRUC_COMP")))\
    .groupBy("ID","ESTRUC_COMP").pivot("key").agg(first("value")).show(truncate=False)
#+---+-----------------------------------+---+---+----+
#|ID |ESTRUC_COMP                        |AP |BQ |IN  |
#+---+-----------------------------------+---+---+----+
#|4A |{'AP': '201', 'BQ': '2'}           |201|2  |null|
#|8B |{'AP': '501', 'BQ': '1', 'IN': '5'}|501|1  |5   |
#+---+-----------------------------------+---+---+----+
```

Of course, since I defined the `udf` to return `MapType(StringType(), StringType())`, all of your resultant columns are going to be strings. You can either [`cast` them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521655/specify-multiple-columns-data-type-changes-to-different-data-types-in-pyspark/51524636#51524636) or modify the `udf` accordingly.